# Two Django Apps on one server

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

So I have been tasked with getting two apps running on one server, which I have done but we think I have misconfigured it as the URL is wrong to access the App and the app has weird errors that shouldn't occur. (Foo/Bar being the initial project already setup on the site and QMS being the app I have created and am trying to add). Possibly worth noting, I have tried other formats such as declaring both WSGIScriptAlias' in the first virtual host, this works however gives me the same URL format.

The URLs are aimed to look like:
mysite.com/foo/bar & mysite.com/QMS

However the current URLS are: 
mysite.com/foo/bar & mysite.com/foo/QMS

The error we are facing is a 'ProgrammingError' from Django where it believes that our DBs do not exist but we have proven they do and we have toyed with the migrations. Anyways on to the relevant config. So I have it setup currently like this:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName web.mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    WSGIScriptAlias /foo /var/www/html/foo/bar/wsgi.py

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html/foo/mediaroot>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName web.mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    WSGIScriptAlias /qms /var/www/html/qms/QMS/wsgi.py
    Alias /static /var/www/html/qms/staticroot/

    <Directory /var/www/html/qms>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you for reading and I would really appreciate any help as this has me stumped!

EDIT: Possible useful info. In the /www/html/foo/ directory there is the main QMS folder inside of it (The dir containing the views & models but not the settings etc. This may relate to the database issues as it's declared in the settings. Also using the django debugger we can see the when on www.mysite.com/foo/QMS it is running the foo/bar settings over the QMS settings)

Comment: You can't have two ``VirtualHost`` definitions with the same ``ServerName`` and same port, only the first will be used. You should have both ``WSGIScriptAlias`` directives in the same ``VirtualHost``. You should though also be using daemon mode of mod_wsgi and delegating each Django instance to run in separate sets of processes.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I have moved to using one VHost since posting this question. However when using DaemonProcess I'm failing to be able to serve two staticroots (one for each app), I've declared them using Alias in the same VHost now I get that it will only use the first and that's the issue I'm facing but how can I get around it?

Comment: They can't both use ``/static``. You will need to use different prefixes for both. What do you currently have for both?

Comment: Yeah I was silly enough to use /static for both haha. It has now been changed and I was missing a following / at the end of the alias. Altering those fixed the problem for me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out and thought I'd answer my question incase someone else was stuck in the same place. So what had me fooled was my work colleague commited a merged version which allowed me to access my URL through their project. This made me believe it was a misconfiguration.

So in order to solve it we removed my App from his, re-uploaded then I added this to my Apps wsgi.py file:

```
path = "/var/www/html/qms"      # Make it the base folder of your app
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
```

And now we are rolling with the correct URLs and my app is now using my settings which solved the errors I was getting.